# 500 Internal error when trying to create channel in MS Teams using MS Graph API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, ms-office

I need to create a channel under a Team using Graph API but keep receiving internal 500 error. Here is my code.

```
    g = Group()
    channel = {
        "displayName": g.channel_name,
        "description": "test channel",
        "membershipType": "standart"
      }

    channel_response = client.post("/teams/{team id}/channels",json.dumps(channel),headers={'Content- 
    Type': 'application/json'})
    get_channels = client.get("/teams/fb9881ab-db9f-4fb5-8039-349082939ca8/channels")
    print(channel_response)
    print(get_channels.content)
```

The response I receive when attempting to create a channel:

```
b'{\r\n  "error": {\r\n    "code": "InternalServerError",\r\n    "message": "Failed to execute request.",\r\n    "innerError": {\r\n      "date": "2021-01-13T22:45:54",\r\n      "request-id": "08ec1984-c8f1-4c71-aa48-c297nx8226fb",\r\n      "client-request-id": "08ec1984-c8f1-4c71-sk48-c297cb8226fb"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}'
```

I can perform a "get channels" request with the same team id.

Any ideas what could be wrong??

Comment: I would suggest you to retry the above API call after sometime, instead of immediate retries. Outside of your code see if the same API works fine or not with POSTMAN/Graph Explorer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix. Seems that it's a bug from MS side.

To create a channel you need to POST payload without "membershipType" argument

```
  channel = {
        "displayName": g.channel_name,
        "description": "test channel"
      }
```